# magento2 after store change redirect to same page

Tags: magento2

I have a different store when I am changing the store it redirects to the home page but I want to redirect to the same page where store changed in Magento 2 
I have written this code

```
?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue("web/unsecure/base_url");
?>
```

through this code it redirects to home page

Comment: That's default magento2 behavior and working fine for me on latest magento 2.3.1, however if you are using older version there's a bug for that. Please, check that answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/259996 .

Comment: Did you create corresponding pages for each store?

Comment: no pages are same only store will different